# icheck checkbox is not working on hover

Tags: jquery, checkbox, hover, icheck

I hover on anchor tag which is contain some block and in block i have icheckbox which is initialize but not working like i can't check checkbox.

```
$('.categories-block input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
    radioClass: 'iradio_minimal, iradio_square-blue',
    increaseArea: '20%'
});
```

And this is on hover code

```
    <a class="download-hover clearfix">
      <ul>
        <li class="first">
            <div class="categories-block">
                <input tabindex="5" type="checkbox">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</a>
```

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: No error in console.

Comment: Can you please provide a running example showing your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there were css not apply and we can't show icheckbox, in this case we have to use `onclick` jquery event and initialize the icheckbox.

Answer (score 1):

Its working here.

```js
$(function(){
 $('.categories-block input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
    radioClass: 'iradio_minimal, iradio_square-blue',
    increaseArea: '20%'
 });
});
```

```css
.categories-block li{
list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/skins/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/icheck.min.js"></script>
<div class="categories-block">
   <a class="download-hover clearfix">
      <ul>
        <li class="first">
            <div class="categories-block">
                <input tabindex="5" type="checkbox"> Check Me
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not exactly  what i do, on anchor tag hover i show a block and in block this icheckbox will show and must be work.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I don't see any anchor tag there, please provide the complete code and what exactly is not working for you?

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: Where is the code for this implementation as you said "on anchor tag hover i show a block and in block this icheckbox will show and must be work"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167708/discussion-between-nitin-dhomse-and-nageen-nayak).

Comment: icheck css file seems not imported in your application please verify that